# Updating documents indexed in solr

Tags: solr, nutch

I am able to crawl a website (using nutch with tika plugin) which contains some pdf and docx files and index the documents created to solr. But after crawling, the data on website changed (some new files added and some old files deleted). So by recrawling the changes are indexed to solr. While querying solr, I also get the links to files that were deleted from the website(obviously). So how do I make configuration/settings so that while indexing to solr (from nutch) all the documents (containing info about files that were deleted from website) also get deleted?

Comment: why don't you delete the existing indexes before recrawling?

Comment: Won't there be any performance issues if I delete all of the existing indexes before recrawling?

Comment: Do you extract content and reindex everything during recrawling? Or do you just index the updated content? If latter is true then that will impact the performance. May be you need to store the state of each content somewhere and accordingly delete selective indexes